# How to make a delete request with Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, web

I am not using resource controller.

The route:

```
Route::delete('/deleteTag/{tag}','Controller2@deleteTag');
```

The controller function:

```
public function deleteTag(Tag $tag){
  $Tag = Tag::where('id', $tag->id)->get()->first();
  $Tag->delete();
  return redirect()->action('Controller2@main');
}
```

The call:

```
<form method="delete" action="http://***/public/deleteTag/{{$tag->id}}"> 
    {!! Form::token() !!} 
    <button type="submit">delete</button>
</form>
```

The program returns a MethodNotAllowedHttpException.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, why do you have "public" in the url?

Comment: I think `delete` is not a valid html method,  you should use `post` and then pass a hidden input for laravel for delete route : `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may try this (Notice the hidden `_method` input):

```
<form method="post" action="http://***/public/deleteTag/{{$tag->id}}"> 
    {!! Form::token() !!}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <button type="submit">delete</button>
</form>
```

Check [Form Method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#form-method-spoofing).

### Update:

In the latest versions of Laravel, it's possible to use blade directives for `csrf` and `method` in the form, for example:

```
<form method="post" action="..."> 
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit">delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: laravel/blade provides a shorthand for csrf tokens and the hidden method:
`@csrf` and `@method('DELETE')` [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Comment: Thanks, I know that but when the answer was given, those were not implemented :-)

Comment: good to know! you may edit the answer according to the new features

Answer (score 1):

It's better to change your route to this mode:

```
Route::resource('tags','TagController');
```

You should register a resourceful route to the controller. This single route declaration creates multiple routes to handle a variety of RESTful actions on the Tag resource.
Remember, since HTML forms can't make PUT, PATCH, or DELETE requests, you will need to add a hidden _method field to spoof these HTTP verbs.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
```

or add this in your form

```
{{method_field('DELETE')}}
```